# Java servlets: How can I encode url as if SessionTrackingMode would be URL?

Tags: java, session, servlets, sessionid, jsessionid

I design web-application based on Java servlets and I'm going to use swfupload (it is Flash component) for uploading files by users.

Problem is that Flash can not send cookie to server. So I need way to add session ID to callback url for Flash. Servlet container can do it (method HttpServletResponse.encodeUrl), but it works only if cookie disabled in browser or SessionTrackingModes is URL.

Is there any way to get URL encoded with jsessionid independently from any other settings?

Answer (score 0):

I found that servlet specification requires sessionID to be encoded as **path parameter** (delimeted by ; (semicolon)) and its name must be "jsessionid".

So I could simply append ';jsessionid=' to URL and it should work with any servlet container.